# dose not get header info at server. i used retrofit 1.9.0 and the method for putting header is

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

```
 OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        httpClient.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("id",id).build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
```

and in server side i use the method ...

```
public function get(){

foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) 

           {  
                  if($name=='id')
                 {
                  $id=$value;
                 }
           }
}
```